# Terminal setup of Bluetooth tethering

Tags: bluetooth

UPDATE: [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Network_Aggregation_Point#BlueZ_5_method) tutorial has some vital info. Firstly, you will need a script called `network-setup` which is in /usr/share/doc/bluez-test-scripts/examples. Copy the `test-network` and the `bluezutils.py` files to `/usr/bin` and run `test-network <MAC address you want to connect to>`.

This worked for the first time but it fails to get IP ever since.

I have successfully managed to connect my Pi Zero to my Android phone but the initiate tethering, I need the GUI (Bluetooth manager). Can I setup tethering from the console and maybe even set it to start at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: `test-network <address> nap`

**NOTE:** To use this outside the `/usr/share/doc/bluez-test-scripts/examples`, you need to copy the `testnetwork` and `bluez-utils.py` files from `/usr/share/doc/bluez-test-scripts/examples` to `/usr/bin` first!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `bluetoothctrl`. See [How to Pair your Bluetooth Device when Using Bluez 5.x](http://patkoscsaba.blogspot.de/2013/12/linux-tip-how-to-pair-your-bluetooth.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say much about setting up PAN, nevertheless you are right about bluetoothctrl. I will try it! Thank you very much!!!